# How to pass bean from action class to other jsp page?

Tags: struts2

It is very simple to do in servlet using `request.setAttribute()`. But how to do this in Struts2?

How to use that bean in other jsp page?

Please give example code.

Answer (score 0):

As @AndreaLigios mentions in the comments, you'll want to generate getters and setters in your action classes.

In your JSP files, you'll be able to get them by using the `<s:property>` tag.